# Filter DATATABLE Rows with multiple Values in columns

Tags: c#, filter, datatable, datarow

I have a DataTable (dt) with multiple columns which is the source to DataGridView. I am trying to filter this DataTable(dt) with a **list of values** of a particular column.

**I need to filter the Below DataTable(dt) with the list of employee names.**
EmpList = {'Pete','Alen'}

This is my DataTable

| Employee | ID | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pete | 1 | USA |
| Mark | 2 | UK |
| Alen | 3 | AUS |

Output needed:

| Employee | ID | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pete | 1 | USA |
| Alen | 3 | AUS |

I am trying it with the below code

```
if (EmpList.Any())
{
  foreach(string item in EmpList)
  {
    var dataRows = from dataRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   where (dataRow.Field<string>("Employee").Contains(item))
                   select dataRow;

    dt.Rows.Add(dataRows);
  }
}
```

The problem is With this block of code, DataType(**System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection[system.Data.DataRow]**) is filling in the Rows of DataTable along with previous Data.

Comment: Do you have a question?  Please read [ask] and post an [mcve].

Comment: My linq foo is weak, but it seems to me that you are searching in `dt` for rows that match `item` and then attempting to add those rows back into `dt`. Do we have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here? Are you trying to build a new table with those elements, or filter the existing table?

Comment: @jwdonahue I am trying to filter the existing data table and assigning to datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the DataTable, you can use the [DefaultView.RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter), join the collection of values to be compared and use the [`IN()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression) operator in the comparison:

```
var names = new[]{ "Allen", "Pete" };
var values = string.Join("', '", names);
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"Employee IN('{values}')";
```

Note that the strings are joined using a comma and a single quote: **`', '`**
To remove the filter, just set it to `string.Empty`.

If you want to return a new DataTable, you can use the [CopyToDataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable) method:

```
var dtFiltered = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(dr => names.Any(s => s.Equals(dr["Employees"]))).CopyToDataTable();
```

You can also assign the DataTable to itself:

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(...).CopyToDataTable();
```

I assume you are already referencing `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`, since you're using `AsEnymerable()` in your code.